# Reference request for a type III action of a group on a manifold

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let an action of a group $\Gamma$ on a manifold $M$ such that $L^{∞}(M)⋊Γ$ is a type $III$ factor.

André Henriques posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141577/a-non-hyperfinite-type-iii-factor-from-an-action-of-the-free-group-on-the-circle#comment365395_141577) the following comment :

> I don't know the literature, so I can't point to a reference, but
> here's how things go:
>
> Given an (let's say a.e. smooth) action of a
> group $Γ$ on a manifold $M$, you can form the bundle of densities
> $Ω^{top}_{>0}M$, which is a principal bundle with structure group
> $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.
> The action of $Γ$ on $M$ induces an action on
> $Ω^{top}_{>0}M$, and the von Neumann algebra $L^{∞}(M)⋊Γ$ is a type
> $III_{1}$ factor iff the action of $Γ$ on $Ω^{top}_{>0}M$ is ergodic.
> If that action is not ergodic, the von Neumann algebra
> $L^{∞}(Ω^{top}_{>0}M)^{Γ}$ is equipped with an action of
> $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ (coming from the action on $Ω^{top}_{>0}M$). This
> corresponds to a action of $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ on some measure space
> $X$. If that action is transitive, it is equivalent to
> $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ acting on $\mathbb{R}_{>0}/\mathbb{Z}^{λ}$ for some
> $λ∈(0,1)$, and the factor $L^{∞}(M)⋊Γ$ is of type $III_{λ}$. Otherwise, $L^{∞}(M)⋊Γ$ is of type $III_{0}$.

Is there a reference for this result (or something close to it) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has nothing to do with manifolds - you are just talking about the classification of type III actions with quasi-invariant measure in terms of their Radon-Nikodym cocycles. It should be contained, for instance, in the old "Indian" book of Klaus Schmidt.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it the following book ? *Cocycles of ergodic transformation groups*. Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Vol. 1, MacMillan (India) 1977. [PDF](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~kschmidt/Publications/rigveda.pdf).  Where is this result on the book, which page ? Is it proved only for the hyperfinite case, or in general ?

Comment: Yes - that's the one I meant, but he doesn't discuss this stuff there. Another standard reference is the book by Hamachi and Osikawa MR0617740,  which surely covers it, but I don't have it with me right now. You can find these statements, for instance, in Section 2 of http://faculty.uml.edu/vprasad/Abelian%20cocycles.pdf (in particular, p. 191).