# Can we solve the FGF problem by finding an appropriate action?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, open-problems, von-neumann-algebras, free-probability

If we can find an action of the free group $\mathbb{F}_2$ on a measure space $X$ such that the crossed product $M=L^∞(X)⋊\mathbb{F}_2$ is a ${\rm III}_1$ factor with core isomorphic to $L(\mathbb{F}_2)⊗B(H)$, then the fundamental group of $L(\mathbb{F}_2)$ is $\mathbb{R}_+$, and the free group factors isomorphism problem is solved.
*Remark*: There is an attempt [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/141577/34538).

*Question*: Can we rule out to solve this problem like that?

*Remark*: One obstruction could be that $M$ admits a Cartan subalgebra whereas $L(\mathbb{F}_2)$ not. To validate this obstruction, it is necessary to prove that the process of taking the core and to truncate it by a projection of trace $1$, keeps the existence of a Cartan subalgebra.

If we can rule out this method:
Can we improve it by replacing $L^∞(X)$ by a more appropriate von Neumann algebra?

More generally:
Could we expect to be able to build *by hand* a ${\rm III}_1$ factor with core $L(\mathbb{F}_2)⊗B(H)$?

Comment: Could you explain the comment about why knowing the fundamental group of $L({\bf F}_2)$ solves the FGF problem?

Comment: @YemonChoi: See this paper of Florin Râdulescu: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=A9C36B7AC7537F510D02C9A364E65E4D?doi=10.1.1.49.1853&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 2):

I do have some models, but only for infinitely many generators. The only thing I can add to what I wrote back then is that the ${\rm III}_{\lambda}$ models are submodels of the ${\rm III}_1$ model. I don't know if we can get $\mathbb{F}_2$.